# Retrieving values from a table cell <td> to a controller

Tags: html, grails, controller, html-table, css-tables

I'm trying to get a specific value from a table cell  and pass is to a controller. But it doesn't seem to be working. I show you some of my codes:

This is in the controller:

```
def searchUser = {
        String abc = request.getParameter("harrow")
        println(abc)
    }
```

This is in the html page:

```
  <form>
 <div style="height: 250px; overflow: scroll; width: 100%;">
              <table id="normal">
              <g:each in = "${result}">
              <tr id="btn">
              <td width=10% >${it.ID}</td>
              <td width=25% id="harrow">${it.username}</td>

              </tr>
              </g:each>


              </table>
         </div>
            <input type ="submit" name ="abc" id="opener">

    </form>
```

**EDIT**

AJAX:

```
 $("#edittable").on('click', function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: URL,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                type: "POST",
                success: function(html){
                    //do something with the `html` returned from the server here
                    $("#edit1").html(html).dialog("open")
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    alert('error: ' + textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
                }
            });
            return false;//suppress natural form selection
        });
```

I can get the value to pass to the controller, but right now it only retrieves the first row of values rather than the other. Is there something wrong with my AJAX codes? Thank you guys so much.

Comment: Forms send `input` elements, so your `<td>` is never being sent to the controller. In fact none of the things on this form except the  `<input type ="submit" name ="abc" id="opener">` will be sent to the controller.

Your form doesn't really make sense as it is.  What are you trying to get the user to do?

Comment: Oh, well, there are input fields, but its just that i remove it. What I'm trying to do here is to have a submit button on the table cell and pass the values to the controller. Thats all.

Comment: You'd have to use hidden fields with the same values as in td. Or td value should be in input text if it is modificable. Still it seems to be not the best approach. If you have table of many rows, which row do you want to send using the button? whole table? maybe it would be better to use ajax and send only required data?

Comment: Hi I used ajax, but whatever data i send, it just retrieves the first row of data. I can update you on my codes.

Comment: So do you want to send all rows to your controller? what you do with this rows? are rows updated in view? please describe what you want to do but not how you want to do this

Comment: Okay so what I want is, the row of data is being retrieved and then it is placed the jquery dialog box with input box inside so that the user can see the values of the rows in these input boxes and edit accordingly to what they want. That is my aim

Answer (score 0):

So to show details of the row, one of the approaches can be:

**CONTROLLER METHODS**

```
def rows = [
        [id:1, name:'name1'],
        [id:2, name:'name2'],
        [id:3, name:'name3']
    ]

def show(){
    [results:rows]
}

def showLine(Long id){
    render rows.find {it.id == id }
}
```

**VIEW**

```
<html>
<head>
    <g:javascript library="jquery" />
    <r:layoutResources />
</head>
<body>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Action</th>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <g:each in="${results}" status="i" var="r">
            <tr>
                <td><g:remoteLink value="Details" id="${r.id}" action="showLine" update="lineDetails">Details</g:remoteLink></td>
                <td>${r.id}</td>
                <td>${r.name}</td>
            </tr>
        </g:each>
    </tbody>
</table>

<div id="lineDetails">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Basically you call showLine method using AJAX and passing row object id. Then you search for the object and render it back. Rendered data is put into div under the table. It's up to you if you use onclick, button or link in the table. It's also up to you how to show details on results page - use jquery dialog, or something else. Hope it helps